# forwarding docker container to nginx port

Tags: nginx, centos, docker, centos7

i have a server that has nginx run on it, and a domain that is been pointed to server, and i have CWP that configured to has nginx on the server.

now i have a docker container that runs on port 3000 of the same server and if i curl into it like `curl http://localhost:3000`, i would get the result.

my question is that how can i forward my domain requests to my docker container that is running on the server, i already did some search, but in my case please not that i dont have any container on the server that boots up nginx separately , its the default nginx on server,

now the question is how can i map port 80 of server (that already pointed to my domain.com) to my running docker container???

Answer (score 1):

Create a server block on the NGINX in the host

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.tld;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NGINX supports WebSockets by allowing a tunnel to be setup between a client and a backend server.

```
# WebSocket proxying
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default         upgrade;
    ''              close;
}


server {
    listen 80;

    # The host name to respond to
    server_name cdn.domain.com;

    location / {
        # Backend nodejs server
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade     $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection  $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does op' mention websocket?